# jquery validation for inputs with definite class

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using jquery validator. I need to add validation rules and messages for input fields with definite class.

Fields:

`'director_front_passport[]','director_back_passport[]','director_address_document[]'`  are arrays and I have a hidden div with the same field names but I need to make required only these fields that have class `director_documents`.

I mean, I have two divs with the same input fields - ther are arrays, but i need to make required only these input fields with class `director_documents`.  How to do that?

My code is:

```js
var images = ['director_front_passport[]','director_back_passport[]','director_address_document[]','corporate_document[]'];
var extn ="jpeg|jpg|gif|png|pdf";
for(var i=0;i< images.length;i++) {
  var $inputImage;
  $inputImage = images[i];
  rules[$inputImage] = {};
  rules[$inputImage].required  = true;
  rules[$inputImage].extension = extn;

  msgs[$inputImage] =  'Please provide an image with one of the following extensions : jpg, gif, png or pdf';

}
var validateObj           = {}
validateObj["rules"]      = rules;
validateObj["messages"]   = msgs;
validateObj["onkeyup"]    = function(element) { $(element).valid();};
validateObj["errorPlacement"] = function(error, element) {
  if($(element).hasClass('app-file')) {
    error.insertAfter($(element).next().next());
  }
  

};
validateObj["success"] = function(element) {};
validateObj["submitHandler"] = function (form) {
  form.submit();
}
$("#form").validate(validateObj);
```

```html
<div class="director-uploads" id="director-uploads1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="director_front_passport" class="col-md-2 director-label-file">{{translate("Front ID/Passport")}}</label>
    <div class="col-md-8 file-wrapper">
      {{ Form::file('director_front_passport[]',  ["class"=>"app-file director_documents"]) }}
      <label for="director_front_passport" class="file-upload"><span>{{translate("Upload a File")}}</span></label>
      <div class="file-name"></div>
      <label for="director_front_passport" generated="true"  class="<?php echo $errors->has('director_front_passport') ? 'error' : '';?>">{{ $errors->first('director_front_passport') }}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="director_back_passport" class="col-md-2 director-label-file">{{translate("Back ID/Passport")}}</label>
    <div class="col-md-8 file-wrapper">
      {{ Form::file('director_back_passport[]',  ["class"=>"app-file director_documents"]) }}
      <label for="director_back_passport" class="file-upload"><span>{{translate("Upload a File")}}</span></label>
      <div class="file-name"></div>
      <label for="director_back_passport" generated="true"  class="<?php echo $errors->has('director_back_passport') ? 'error' : '';?>">{{ $errors->first('director_back_passport') }}</label>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using HTML5 validators? You could use a regex to check for your image extensions (similar to the way email is being validated below).
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

To change the validation message you can use oninvalid:

```
<input type="text" id="username" required placeholder="Enter Name"
    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter User Name Here')"
    oninput="setCustomValidity('')"  />

Website: <input type="url" name="website" required pattern="https?://.+">
Email Address: <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Enter a valid email address">
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```js
for(var i=0;i< images.length;i++) {
  var $inputImage;
  $inputImage = images[i]; 
  if($('input[name="' + $inputImage + '"]').hasClass('director_documents')) {
    rules[$inputImage] = {}; console.log(1);
    rules[$inputImage].required = true;
    rules[$inputImage].extension = extn;

    msgs[$inputImage] = 'Please provide an image with one of the following extensions : jpg, gif, png or pdf';
  }

}
```